# When i minimise any app in my iPhone Does that app runs in background? or Pauses? or stops the app ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a doubt that i have iPhone 3G and iPhone 4 both and if i run my app and test in those devices like if i press the home button of my iPhone and open some other app and again if i open my app, **in iPhone 4 my app opens the screen where i minimized it** , **in iPhone 3 my app starts from splash screen i mean the app restarts from beginning**.
I don't know why this is happening is this my code problem or this is the iPhone's multitasking problem? When i minimize any app in my iPhone Does that app runs in background? or Pauses? or stops the app?  ***what actually happens when i minimize my app in both generation phones***  Any help is appreciated in advance thank you.

Comment: in iPhone3 it will close it. In iPhone 4 it will suspend it. AppDeleget will get a notification when app comes in foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app goes to the background and stays there as long as it can. If memory gets short, the app terminates.

How the device handles background application is more a function of the iOS than the device. Even 2nd generation phones running iOS 4.0 have multitasking.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 3G doesn't support multitasking, only 3Gs, 4 and iPads. As for background tasks, you have to implement background functionality, like playing music or downloading something or sending local notifications, by yourself.

Comment: 3G is able to run 4.2.1 so it supports multitasking.

Comment: Running iOS4 doesn't mean the device supports multitasking. 3G supports multitasking only on jailbroken devices with Cydia and Backgrounder installed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). In discussion part of method called `applicationDidEnterBackground:` you can find answer on your question.